# Minimum clustering of API Manager with Internal Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to set up a clustered environment for WSO2 API Manager. In the environment I need there is no need for an external store. I looking to start with the least amount of nodes and JVMs that yet is scalable with growing number of API requests.

Having looked at the WSO2 [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/API+Manager+Clustering+Deployment+Patterns)
Clustering WSO2 API Manager and specifically the "Store and Publisher components in a single server node" model.

Some questions on this deployment model
Where is the Gateway Manager deployed?

I understand the publisher and store are on the same server node. Can they be run in the same JVM? If so would you use the default profile that also starts up KM and Gateway or soemthing else?

(Appologies but I can't post the image due to my low reputation value. I would have thought the image of the model would have helped)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - API Store and Publisher will be running in the same JVM. As there is no profile for Store & Publisher (see [1] for available profiles), we need to start API Manager in the default profile. And yes it will start KM & Gateway components as well. But you can block (not expose) gateway ports. And regarding gateway manager, I guess one gateway node can act as both manager and worker in this deployment pattern.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Product+Profiles

Comment: Thank you.
As for your suggestion on the Gateway Manager on the same node as the Gateway Worker, I guess the recommendation is to have the Manager running in a separate process from the Gateway Worker. Accomplished by using two installations and starting them with the profiles gateway-worker and gateway-manager respectively, correct?

Answer (score 0):

As per the design publisher is a subset of store. So, If you start with profile api-store you will eventually get publisher as well. In this case you can start the server with following option.

-Dprofile=api-store